# How can I use threading to get data and write data to the same text file

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-multithreading

Regarding to these data that are related to the following code,

```
12      41      58      82000
12      41      58      190000
12      41      58      301000
12      41      58      416000
12      41      58      524000
12      41      58      632000
12      41      58      741000
12      41      58      849000
12      41      58      959000
12      41      59      65000
12      41      59      174000
12      41      59      281000
12      41      59      389000
12      41      59      496000
12      41      59      605000
12      41      59      711000
12      41      59      820000
12      41      59      927000
12      42      0      36000
12      42      0      143000
12      42      0      252000
12      42      0      360000
12      42      0      469000
12      42      0      577000
12      42      0      685000
12      42      0      793000
12      42      0      901000
12      42      1      9000
```

the code is here:

```
from datetime import datetime
minute = 0
second = 0
microsecond=0
fob=open('test_file_thread.txt','w')

def st():
    global hour
    global minute
    exacttime = datetime.now()
    hour = exacttime.hour
    minute = exacttime.minute

def nd():
    global second
    global microsecond
    exacttime = datetime.now()
    second = exacttime.second
    microsecond = exacttime.microsecond

while True:
    st()
    nd()
    fob.write(str(hour) + '      '
              + str(minute) + '      '
              + str(second) + '      '
              + str(microsecond) + '\n')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Now I would like to do the same with threading.
I am using two threads to get data from two serial ports. As threads work in parallel, I cannot make a text file to arrange the data row by row.That is, I want to get the data from first serial port, write it to row=0 and column=0 of a text file, then read the data from second serial port and write it to row=0 and column=5(so it is exactly in front of data from the first port), then go to the next line (row=1) and repeat this procedure.
I would like to have something like the "time example" that I made above with reading from serial port. This is my code and I don't know how to fix it and where to put command `fob.write(str(x)+'      ' +str(y)+'\n')` to write every thing in the same time to the same file.
Thank for any help

```
import time, threading
import threading
import serial
x=0
y=0
fob=open('test_file_thread.txt','w')
ser1 = serial.Serial("COM5", baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
ser2 = serial.Serial("COM4", baudrate=9600, timeout=0.25)

def st():
    global x
    while True:
        x = ser1.readline()
def nd():
    global y
    while True:
        y= ser2.readline()

threading.Timer(0, st).start()
threading.Timer(0, nd).start()
fob.write(str(x)+'      ' +str(y)+'\n')
```

Comment: If the two threads reading serial ports are running concurrently and likely generating data at different rates, why to do you want data from the first port next to data from the second port om the same line, which was probably read at different point in time (or maybe hasn't even been read yet)? Regardless, the way this sort of problem is usually handled is by putting the data into a `Queue.Queue` in the various threads and then getting data from it in another (and writing it to a file in the latter).

Comment: Regarding your question,as it is written in the code, the two serial ports are working with different timeout. But those times are related to each other. It is not necessary if one variable is updated another one also get a new value; it can be repeated. Imagine that you are running.One variable can be your heart rate and another one can be your speed. In this example it is possible that your speed is changing suddenly, while your heart rate changes gradually. So you would have the same heart rate for couple of seconds while your speed in all of those seconds has been changed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Queue, actually two of them!

```
from Queue import Queue
...
ST_Q = Queue()
MD_Q = Queue()

def st():
    ST_Q.put(ser1.readline())

def md():
    MD_Q.put(ser2.readline())

threading.Timer(0, st).start()
threading.Timer(0, nd).start()
#while loop here?    
fob.write(str(ST_Q.get())+'      ' +str(MD_Q.get())+'\n')
```

Comment: `threading.Timer`s only execute the supplied function after the delay _once_, they won't call it repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Yoav Glazner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741460/yoav-glazner)
Actually i have found a new way that I guess also is a good solution. 
I think about dedicating a new thread only for writing. It worked for me. What do you think?

```
import time, threading
import threading
from datetime import datetime
hour=0
minute = 0
second = 0
microsecond=0
fob=open('test_file_thread.txt','w')

def st():
    global hour
    global minute
    while True:

        exacttime = datetime.now()
        hour = exacttime.hour
        minute = exacttime.minute

def nd():
    global second
    global microsecond
    while True:

        exacttime = datetime.now()
        second = exacttime.second
        microsecond = exacttime.microsecond

def hd():
    while True: 
        fob.write(str(hour) + ' '+ str(minute) + ' '+ str(second) + ' '+ str(microsecond) + '\n')


threading.Timer(0, st).start()
threading.Timer(0, nd).start()
threading.Timer(0, hd).start()
```

Comment: You still need a way to block your main thread. maybe call **join** on the *hd* thread...

Comment: What could happen if I don't block the main thread and if I don't call join oh 'hd' thread? The problem is that I am using infinite loop inside "nd" and "st", so I cannot wait until they finish their works

Comment: I guess that if they are daemon threads than it doesn't mater, but it will look more readable (it will tell that the script does not *end* :))